# Xcode 6.4 cannot connect to action, code unchanged from Xcode 6.3.

Tags: xcode

I have some code from a project that displays a value using the NSLevelIndicatorCell. In 6.3 the code worked and the indicator moved and responded correctly. Since the upgrade to Xcode 6.4 I get a runtime error that reads:

*2015-09-12 10:56:03.801 dispalt[1627:229793] Could not connect action, target class FlightDisplayWindowController does not respond to -Tempbar:*

I checked and in the IB the Outlet appears to be correctly connected, other outlets for NSTextFields are also connected and work. I have searched and so far found nothing about this problem. Anyone any ideas?

the .h file code is :

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface FlightDisplayWindowController : NSWindowController {
__weak NSLevelIndicator *Tempbar;
IBOutlet NSTextField *Temp1;
IBOutlet NSImageView *AltDsply;
IBOutlet NSTextField *Alt1;


}
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLevelIndicator *Tempbar;
- (IBAction)Close:(id)sender;
- (void)updateTempbarDisplay: (id) text;

@end
```

and the .m file element is:

```
- (void)updateTempbarDisplay: (id) text
{
    float Temp =[text floatValue];

    NSString *tempstr =[[NSString alloc] initWithString: text];
    [Temp1 setStringValue:tempstr];
    [Tempbar setFloatValue:Temp];
}
```

cheers
Stephen

Comment: 1. Try to reconnect it.  2. You have broken backing variable of Tempbar. Xcode autosynthesizes it as @synthesize Tempbar = _Tempbar; with underscore. So if you have property with own backing variable make sure it matches default or write your own syntesizer

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Still don't know why it was broken, something strange happen during the switch to Xcode 6.4. Still all good works again now.